# PWM Charge Controllers: Common types and example schematics?

Tags: pwm, dc-dc-converter, solar-cell, lead-acid, solar-charge-controller

I started on this quest because I needed to connect my programmable supply (KD3005P) 30V-5A to the PV input of a [Landstar 1024B PWM Charge controller](https://www.epever.com/upload/file/1811/LS-B-SMS-EL-V2.5.pdf) to test out the charging functionality of the controller and see what affect it has on the load.  I didn't have good sunlight to run an actual panel.  My programmable supply has current limiting features and [I've read that some PWM controllers will actually short the PV leads together to drop the voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/443780/341378). So I thought this was fine.

I use this charge controller to control the load and sometimes for different projects, when I don't have panels, I put a dumb lead acid battery charger at the PV input.  But I'm worried now that perhaps that could kill my supply and I want to better understand the different types of PWM Controllers.

From what I gather, PWM are different from MPPT in that PWM do not vary switching to determine maximum power - just constant current/voltage or following through different charging states that switch between the two.  This question is not about MPPT.

Do pwm controllers implement boost/buck converters?  Most I've seen are just buck.  Is it common to short the PV input?  Is it typically safe to connect a DC supply to the PV input of a controller or is that only for certain topologies? If so, which?

[image: PWM Charge controller with source16v, bat12v, load30r connected]